# Solving two variable using two expressions each involving summation

Tags: equation-solving, summation

I am trying to solve for `h1` and `h2` using function solve as in below code, Expression in solve has two equation each equates sum of two expression. Both left hand and right hand side of second expression is the sum of eight quantities. `h1` is used for first $4$ and `h2` is used for next $4$ for second expression in both left and right hand side. Fist expression in solve is also very similar to second except that it is sum of four quantities and uses just `h1`.

I am getting correct value of `h1` if I just solve fist equation. However when I am using two expression I am getting error:

```
Solve[
Sum[50/10000*1/4*1/4*n*97/100*Exp[-h1*1/4*n], {n, 1, 4}] == 
Sum[1/2*1/4*n*97/100*(Exp[-h1*1/4*(n - 1)] - Exp[-h1*1/4*n]), {n, 
1, 4}]  &&   
Sum[77/10000*1/4*1/4*n*97/100*Exp[-h1*1/4*n], {n, 1, 4}] + 
Sum[77/10000*1/4*1/4*n*94/100*Exp[-h2*1/4*n], {n, 5, 8}] == 
Sum[1/2*1/4*n*97/100*(Exp[-h1*1/4*(n - 1)] - Exp[-h1*1/4*n]), {n, 1, 4}] 
Sum[1/2*1/4*n*94/100*(Exp[-h2*1/4*(n - 1)] - Exp[-h2*1/4*n]), {n, 5,8}],   
{h1, h2}, Reals]
```

The output of Solve is

```
{{h1 -> 0.00998752, h2 -> 0.00998752}}
```

The error message observed is :

> "The front end encountered an error while processing a "NotebookPredictions" packet".

Can anybody `pl` help in understanding error and help solving `h1` and `h2` Please?

Comment: With Mathematica 10.1, I receive no error messages, but I also receive an empty list for an answer.  By the way, please edit your question to remove the single quotes from the beginning and end of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  wrote:

> Both left hand and right hand side of second expression is the sum of eight quantities

So I guessed your Mathematica expression is wrong. You forgot a Plus sign here

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, after correcting:

```
Solve[.... == ... .. && ... + ... == ... + ...] // N

{{h1 -> 0.00998752, h2 -> 0.017552}, {h1 -> 0.00998752, h2 -> 5.94171}}
```

The aimless debugger strikes again.

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in a comment, there are no `Reals` solutions to your equations.  There are, however, 17 `Complex` solutions, obtained by deleting `Reals` from `Solve`.  One such solution is,

```
{h1 -> ConditionalExpression[-4 (2 I π C[1] - Log[401/400]), C[1] ∈ Integers], 
 h2 -> ConditionalExpression[-4 (2 I π C[2] + Log[Root[958425069093800 -
          365632940319875 #1^4 + 394755132106120 #1^5 + 488331476140139 #1^6 + 
          581907820174158 #1^7 + 1333623456783952 #1^8 &, 1]]), C[2] ∈ Integers]}
```

The list of solutions, designated for convenience as `s`, can be simplified by

```
N[Simplify[s, C[1] ∈ Integers && C[2] ∈ Integers]] // Expand
```

yielding

```
{{h1 -> 0.00998752 - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.0260711 + 11.2987 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> 0.00998752 - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.0260711 - 11.2987 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> 0.00998752 - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.0694075 + 7.68613 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> 0.00998752 - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.0694075 - 7.68613 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> 0.00998752 - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.0484291 + 5.20504 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> 0.00998752 - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.0484291 - 5.20504 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> 0.00998752 - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.516819 + 1.70172 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> 0.00998752 - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.516819 - 1.70172 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> (2.00463 - 12.5664 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.631895 - 12.5664 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> (2.00463 - 12.5664 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.62406 - 6.33258 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> (2.00463 - 12.5664 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.62406 + 6.33258 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> (1.77028 - 6.73299 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.631895 - 12.5664 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> (1.77028 - 6.73299 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.62406 - 6.33258 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> (1.77028 - 6.73299 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.62406 + 6.33258 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> (1.77028 + 6.73299 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.631895 - 12.5664 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> (1.77028 + 6.73299 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.62406 - 6.33258 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}, 
 {h1 -> (1.77028 + 6.73299 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[1], 
  h2 -> (0.62406 + 6.33258 I) - (0. + 25.1327 I) C[2]}}
```

Since `C[1]` and `C[2]` are integers, none of the `h2` are real, as predicted.

With respect to the error you observed, I suggest you restart Mathematica, which often eliminates unusual errors.

Comment: @belisarius. I am struggling a bit to interpret the result. Can you guys help me to understand. I am using excel goal to get value of h1 and h2 and comparing it with mathematica result. I understand excel goal seek gives real values only. I am applying goal seek on 1st expression to get value of h1 which is 0.03959. I am applying goal seek on 2nd expression and using value of h1 (i.e. 0.03959) to get value of h2. I get h2 to be 0.05631. How come I get so different values from excel goal seek and Mathematica solve please?

Comment: sorry h1 is 0.01148 and h2 is 0.01451. I a not that worried about but h2 is far off with two different values from mathematica.

Comment: The solution by @Belisarius to your corrected equations is correct, suggesting that you have a problem with Excel, which is beyond the scope of this site.  By the way, your equations can be converted to polynomials by the substitution `{h1 -> -4 Log[x1], h2 -> -4 Log[x2]}`.

Comment: Thanks. I am just wondering if Solve is right function to use or I use Minimze function as I am trying to minimize difference between two equation using goal seek in excel. these two equation being nonlinear solve is giving few alternative solutions. I need to extend to h3,h4 and h5. Probably then its impossible to for Solve function find a reasonable solution however excel goal seek keeps minimizing it nicely